# Can't hear the Django user_logged_out signal

Tags: django, django-views

OK, using the new-ish 'user_logged_in' signal in Django 1.3, and it works great. But, the corresponding 'user_logged_out' signal appears to be getting ignored. Let's assume I'm just trying to log the logins & logouts using a module called transaction.  Again, the login bit works great, but the logout looks like it's being ignored... No error messages anywhere, and nothing in my resulting logs.  OK, here's the code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.utils import transaction

@receiver(user_logged_out)
def log_logout(sender, **kwargs):
    u = kwargs['user'].username 
    data={ 'Successful Logout': u } 
    transaction.add(data)

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def log_login(sender, **kwargs):
    u = kwargs['user'].username 
    data={ 'Successful Login': u }
    transaction.add(data)
```

...I've tested this a couple different ways, and I can't seem to get the user_logged_out signal to fire (or, be heard).  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It only fires when the user is logged out, so how are you logging out the user?

Comment: I'm using the standard django logout function... from urls.py:     (r'^accounts/logout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/logout'}), ...which certainly calls .logout(), which should fire the signal, right?

Comment: Are you sure about that urls.py? First glace looks like cyclical loop (your logout is redirecting to /logout)

Comment: I thought that the next_page was for redirecting after django logged the user out... Anyway, thanks, burhan.  You may have solved two issues for me.  I just realized that my logout link wasn't working, either, so these issues are probably related.  I'm gonna go work on this a little...

Comment: OK, that was it.  Thanks, burhan, for helping me kill two birds with one stone!